# Is there a method to create permanent connections between locations or planes to each other to only allow communication?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, planes

Related questions:

- [Are there any spells or magic items that allow for making of ‘logic gates or wires’?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141573/are-there-any-spells-or-magic-items-that-allow-for-making-of-logic-gates-or-wir)
- [Are there methods to allow players to create permanent gates between planes/demiplanes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141686/are-there-methods-to-allow-players-to-create-permanent-gates-between-planes-demi)

Is there a method for the party could allow the setup to function across planes and very distant locations in some manner? It needs to be receivable by things other than creatures as well if possible.

Comment: To confirm, you're asking if there's a way to freely communicate between different planes? Presumably, the Sending spell is insufficient for this?

Comment: "It needs to be receivable by things other than creatures." What kind of "things" you mean here? Radio? Crystall ball? Scrying sensor? What?

Comment: Exactly, and it is related to the logic gates or wires question is that there might be a desire to stretch the link across the plane, meaning it has to be an actual audio, visual, or other signal so the Magic mouth can detect it

Comment: Though I feel that it being able to be received by scrying sensor or crystal ball would work as well

Comment: I’m running a very plane heavy campaign and am trying to figure out how to do some of the things my players want to do

Comment: Yea. Are you trying to create a walkie talkie? or perhaps something closer to CCTV? Or Interplanar YouTube? I agree with Naut that your actual goal would help.

Comment: Pretty much all of those

Comment: To be clear, is this a case of your players asking "how can we communicate across the planes?" and you, not knowing, asking us? Have the players proposed any ideas? Or, is this a case where you are anticipating this need and trying to solve this issue for them?

Comment: The setting is one where the planes have gone out of whack, locations from planes appearing on others, prime worlds scrambling with each other, the questions are mostly due to the fact there is going to be a large amount of planer travel, separation of the group across planes(8 player groups, we play 4 people at a time, alternating). Their base needs to be very secure, or at least have a monitoring system, and there is a need for them to be able to make permanent methods of fast transport to avoid the astral plane, which is flooded by creatures from the outer planes, battling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Let your players play

You've got a very interesting and different world. Rather than trying to come up with solutions for your players, let them come up with ways they want to do things and then adjudicate whether or not they'll work.

You can ask the specific methods here if you want another opinion, but your world is up to you and you can reward your players for creative thinking if you like their plans.

### Worldbuilding

If you want these systems in place, you are very free to create them. Given your world is not standard, you are more than free (you are encouraged!) to develop systems that work for you. Trying to force the square peg standard rules into your homebrew situation may not be the best fit and you are definitely free to utilize existing content in new and interesting ways that fit your narrative.

You want Teleportation Circles to be cross-planar? Go for it! You want *sending* or Sending Stones to work that way - make 'em! Don't be afraid to homebrew mechanics for your homebrew world!

Comment: I need a way for them to get around without being slaughtered by the hoards of gith, astral dreadnoughts, and other creatures warring in the astral

Comment: @EjSizemore Do you want these systems in place upon immediate start of campaign for their use?

Comment: They will learn/acquire the method after arriving in sigil, one of the few safe places left

Comment: Thanks, and when I think about it, my setting is so chaotic that many of the existing rules probably wouldn’t work, for example, Earth(planet, not plane) is meting mushed up with a ton of planes. Modrons falling from the moon, the international space station covered in the most chaotically topped pizza, Mount Everest acting like a miniature mount Celestia, and the Mariana Trench being a watery opening to the abyss